# Insert multiple rows into database from json containing multidimensional data

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, prepared-statement, sql-insert

This is the following JSON I am working with. I have everything being pulled and added correctly except the content under "tactics" --   which comes out as `Array`.

My goal is to store the "tactics" values as a comma-delimited string.

```
'[
{
  "queryFrequency": "P1D",
  "queryPeriod": "P1D",
  "triggerOperator": "GreaterThan",
  "triggerThreshold": 0,
  "eventGroupingSettings": {
    "aggregationKind": "SingleAlert"
  },
  "severity": "Medium",
  "query": "let extess",
  "suppressionDuration": "PT1H",
  "suppressionEnabled": false,
  "tactics": [
    "Execution",
    "Persistence"
  ],
  "displayName": "MFA disabled for a user",
  "enabled": true,
  "description": "Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) helps prevent credential compromise. This alert identifies when an attempt has been made to diable MFA for a user ",
  "alertRuleTemplateName": "65c78944-930b-4cae-bd79-c3664ae30ba7",
  "lastModifiedUtc": "2021-06-16T16:29:52.6974983Z",
  "name": "1ada95bc-b4d5-4776-bc3e-2dbb3684c0b1",
  "id": "/sc0b1",
  "kind": "Scheduled",
  "createIncident": true,
  "groupingConfiguration": {
    "enabled": false,
    "reopenClosedIncident": false,
    "lookbackDuration": "PT5H",
    "entitiesMatchingMethod": "All",
    "groupByEntities": [
      "Account",
      "Ip",
      "Host",
      "Url",
      "FileHash"
    ]
  },
  "playbookName": ""
},
{
  "queryFrequency": "P1D",
  "queryPeriod": "P1D",
  "triggerOperator": "GreaterThan",
  "triggerThreshold": 0,
  "eventGroupingSettings": {
    "aggregationKind": "SingleAlert"
  },
  "severity": "Medium",
  "query": "StppUsed",
  "suppressionDuration": "PT1H",
  "suppressionEnabled": false,
  "tactics": [
    "Execution",
    "Persistence"
  ],
  "displayName": "Explicit MFA Deny",
  "enabled": true,
  "description": "User explicitly denies MFA push, indicating that login was not expected and the account\'s password may be compromised.",
  "alertRuleTemplateName": "a22740ec-fc1e-4c91-8de6-c29c6450ad00",
  "lastModifiedUtc": "2021-06-16T16:29:54.0826821Z",
  "name": "bba57ceb-dd33-4297-8080-b19b1bd07a21",
  "id": "/suobba5d07a21",
  "kind": "Scheduled",
  "createIncident": true,
  "groupingConfiguration": {
    "enabled": false,
    "reopenClosedIncident": false,
    "lookbackDuration": "PT5H",
    "entitiesMatchingMethod": "All",
    "groupByEntities": [
      "Account",
      "Ip",
      "Host",
      "Url",
      "FileHash"
    ]
  },
  "playbookName": ""
    }  ]'
```

This is my code:

```
...
$dep_cols=array("queryFrequency","queryPeriod","triggerOperator","triggerThreshold","aggregationKind","severity","query","suppressionDuration","suppressionEnabled","tactics","displayName","enabled","description","kind","createIncident","playbookName");  // declare columns
    $dep_keys=array_map(function($v){return ":$v";},$dep_cols);  // build :keys    
    $dep_cols=array_combine($dep_keys,$dep_cols);   // assign :keys
    var_export($dep_cols);
    $dep_query="INSERT INTO `template_rules` (`id`,`".implode('`,`',$dep_cols)."`)"; // list columns as csv
    $dep_query.=" VALUES ('',".implode(',',array_keys($dep_cols)).");";
    echo "<div>$dep_query</div>";
    $stmt_add_dep=$db->prepare($dep_query);
        
    foreach(json_decode($json) as $d){
        foreach($dep_cols as $k=>$v){
            if($k==':tactics'){$v=json_decode($v);}
            $stmt_add_dep->bindValue($k,(property_exists($d,$v)?$d->$v:""));
            echo "<div>$k => {$d->$v}</div>";
        }
        $stmt_add_dep->execute();
        echo "<div>Dep Affected Rows: ",$stmt_add_dep->rowCount(),"</div><br>";
    }
...
```

If I remove the `if($k==':tactics')` statement, I just get `Array`. I'm not sure how to pull those values out as they look to just be a string in an array.

Current results look like this:

```
...
:suppressionDuration => PT1H
:suppressionEnabled =>
:tactics =>
:displayName => MFA disabled for a user
:enabled => 1
...
```

Comment: I would like to see `var_export(json_decode($json))` as part of the [mcve].

Comment: How exactly do you wish for `"tactics": ["Execution", "Persistence"]` to be stored in your `:tactics` column?  Are you storing the two values as a json string, as a comma-delimited string, something else?  What is your goal?

Comment: @mickmackusa My goal is to do it as a comma-delimited string. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working refactor of your script.

Create arrays of the whitelisted column names and a number of placeholders (I prefer the vague `?`, but you can use named placeholders if you like).

Create separate payloads of values to be fed to the prepared statement when `execute()` is called.

You don't need to mention `id` if you are autoincrementing that column.

Code: ([PHPize.online Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/528db2a92aed47b50e52b9e8ad2fc918/php/php81/c6352d339e33900daac4efc0f05a628c/))

```
$whitelist = [
    "queryFrequency", "queryPeriod", "triggerOperator", "triggerThreshold",
    "aggregationKind", "severity", "query", "suppressionDuration",
    "suppressionEnabled", "tactics", "displayName", "enabled",
    "description", "kind", "createIncident", "playbookName"
];

$columns = [];
$placeholders = [];
$valueSets = [];
foreach ($whitelist as $column) {
    $columns[] = "`$column`";
    $placeholders[] = "?";
}
foreach (json_decode($json) as $i => $obj) {
    $obj->aggregationKind = $obj->eventGroupingSettings->aggregationKind ?? null;
    $obj->tactics = property_exists($obj, 'tactics') ? implode(',', $obj->tactics) : null;
    foreach ($whitelist as $column) {
        $valueSets[$i][] = $obj->$column ?? null;
    }
}
    
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
    sprintf(
        'INSERT INTO `template_rules` (%s) VALUES (%s)',
        implode(',', $columns),
        implode(',', $placeholders)
    )
);
foreach ($valueSets as $values) {
    $stmt->execute($values);
    printf("<div>New autoincremented Id: %d</div><br>\n\n", $pdo->lastInsertId());
}

echo json_encode($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM template_rules')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the help. I learned a few things tonight :)